# How to get all data from another table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I create a `view` and try to copy the data to the table every hour.

In this process, I'm trying to use below commands.

```sql
DELETE TABLE;
INSERT INTO TABLE SELECT * FROM VIEW;
```

This process takes about 3 seconds.

However, if there is a lot of data later, I think it will take more time.

So, is there any way to quickly move the data in the view?

A view is to calculate a specific ranking, and only the same data may exist, only different data may exist, and the same data and different data may exist together.

thank you

Comment: TRUNCATE is quicker than DELETE (but may not be appropriate for you). Also why a view over the selects used in the view?

Comment: You don't "move data into a view". A view is just a saved query, it doesn't have a copy of the data. Some databases have "materialized views" which do make a snapshot of the data, but MySQL doesn't.

Comment: @P.Salmon View has multiple calculated values. Code is long, so I created a view.

Comment: @Barmar This is not to move data to the view, but to move the data in the view to the table. As answered, mView doesn't exist, so I'm trying to do this.

Comment: No, there's no faster way. It has to calculate the results to move, and that takes time.

Comment: Code is long - is not generally a reason for creating a view and if you have optimised it there's not much more you can do other than acquire bigger,faster computer

Comment: @Barmar understand. Thanks you for the replies!

Comment: @P.Salmon understand. Thanks you for the replies!